# How can I make my nav bar items slide down on hover? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I've tried searching for this, but it seems like everyone asking anything similar is looking for something more complex so none of the answers gave me much insight.

I'm not going for a drop down menu, just a simple animation to indicate the navigation option the user's mouse is over. This is the jQuery code I have currently, which produces no effect at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(nav li).mouseenter(function(){
        $(nav li).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

Why won't this work, and what will?

Comment: because `$(nav li)` is not a valid jQuery selector. Read about valid selectors [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(nav li)` is incorrect change it to `$('nav li')` i.e within quotation marks.

for making all `nav li`  `slideDown`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav li").mouseenter(function () {
        $("nav li").slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

for making current `nav li`  `slideDown`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("nav li").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Of course it would be a simple typo that I've somehow managed to be blind to for 3 days. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :hover css pseudo class to achieve this effect, and CSS transitions to add an animation effect.

```
ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    background:red;
    margin-right:10px;
    transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}

ul li:hover{
    background:orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cx6Yr/1/

Comment: Good point, thank you. I'm focusing on jQuery right now because I'm learning it, but the reminder that it's not always necessary is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotation marks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav li").mouseenter(function(){
        $("nav li").slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```